# Choosing big data warehouse

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, cloudera, cassandra-2.0, bigdata

Nowadays I've been challenged by creating data warehouse to store and process huge amount of data. Estimated amount is over 7 billions events per day. The data should be kept for the 7 days. Average event size is ~0.5 - 1 Kb. We need to process the data to:

- generate reports;
- train models.

Currently I'm evaluating:

- Google Bigquery
- Redshift
- Stratio + Cassandra + AWS + EMR + EBS
- Cloudera + AWS

So I'm interested in:

- solution you use inside your company( frameworks, setup, database, amount of nodes, etc )
- any real cost examples/comparison if possible
- management complexity( devops )

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: @MoralesBatovski it is not, the topic is bigger and involves software solutions and frameworks like from Stratio and Cloudera company. And bigquery is elastic and works only via API...

Comment: too broad and offtopic.

Comment: @ZigMandel questions are concrete and relates to experience in big data warehouse. If you have valuable input and expirience in this field - you are welcome

Comment: tske a look at the reason its marked offtopic. you are precicely asking for tool recommendations which are clearly offtopic. spend time learning the specifics and ask a specific programming question.

Comment: I'm choosing technology stack not a tool. This is a big difference.

Answer (score 4):

I recently wrote this summary based on Mark Lit's series comparing BigQuery, Spark, Hive, Presto, ElasticSearch, AWS Redshift, AWS EMR, and Google Dataproc:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/bigquery-and-dataproc-shine-in-independent-big-data-platform-comparison

Summary of the summary:

- Same dataset (1 billion rows), same queries, many technologies and configurations.
- BigQuery was the fastest to run queries: 2 seconds.
- BigQuery was the only one fast by default: There were no optimizations needed or data pre-processing required. 1 billion rows were loaded in 25 minutes, and data was ready to be queried.
- Other solutions took hours to load data (at a significant cost), and were many times slower than BigQuery.

But the best benchmark you can get is your own: Trying BigQuery should be fast and easy. Then try to find another platform that loads data as fast, queries it as fast, or gets close to it in price. Mark tried, and those were his findings.

Answer (score 1):

We use BigQuery, pros:

- SQL, column based
- supports JSON data in columns --> advantage, unstructured
- extremely cheap 1 Petabyte around $21k per month.
- managed service by Google, no devops
- 100 000 rows / second ingestion capability
- see slide [#24](http://www.slideshare.net/martonkodok/complex-realtime-event-analytics-using-bigquery-crunch-warmup/24) from linked presentation

More use cases and architecture you find: http://www.slideshare.net/martonkodok/complex-realtime-event-analytics-using-bigquery-crunch-warmup

Comment: any cons you found from your experience?

Comment: Lack of professional support, weird API errors, need very advanced SQL devs, but this is fun.